# Editing Spring Boot CLI default

Tags: spring-boot, command-line-interface, default

I am running commands like `spring init --build=maven firstProj` and I want to add default parameters to these commands.

I'm looking to be able to set the `--build=maven` parameter as default however, the initalizr autobuilds my projects with gradle.

Below is a segement of the relevant `spring init --list`

```
Project types (* denotes the default)
+-----------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
| Id                    | Description                                                  | Tags                                       |
+-----------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
| gradle-build          | Generate a Gradle build file.                                | build:gradle,format:build                  |
|                       |                                                              |                                            |
| gradle-project *      | Generate a Gradle based project archive using the Groovy     | build:gradle,dialect:groovy,format:project |
|                       | DSL.                                                         |                                            |
|                       |                                                              |                                            |
| gradle-project-kotlin | Generate a Gradle based project archive using the Kotlin     | build:gradle,dialect:kotlin,format:project |
|                       | DSL.                                                         |                                            |
|                       |                                                              |                                            |
| maven-build           | Generate a Maven pom.xml.                                    | build:maven,format:build                   |
|                       |                                                              |                                            |
| maven-project         | Generate a Maven based project archive.                      | build:maven,format:project                 |
+-----------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+


Parameters
+-------------+------------------------------------------+------------------------------+
| Id          | Description                              | Default value                |
+-------------+------------------------------------------+------------------------------+
| artifactId  | project coordinates (infer archive name) | demo                         |
| bootVersion | spring boot version                      | 3.1.0                        |
| description | project description                      | Demo project for Spring Boot |
| groupId     | project coordinates                      | com.example                  |
| javaVersion | language level                           | 17                           |
| language    | programming language                     | java                         |
| name        | project name (infer application name)    | demo                         |
| packageName | root package                             | com.example.demo             |
| packaging   | project packaging                        | jar                          |
| type        | project type                             | gradle-project               |
| version     | project version                          | 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT               |
+-------------+------------------------------------------+------------------------------+
```